# "Doubled" appended custom shapes

Tags: rigging, append

When I append a rig with control shapes, the shapes appear “doubled up”, once in a normal Object form – white in the screenshot – and again in a Rig form which can open in Edit and Pose – blue in the screenshot. (The purple Empty is just a control for the whole rig.)

Any idea why this happens?

[image: appended rig]

Comment: Check if you have ***mirror modifier*** turned on

Comment: Thanks Akai – Ray had the answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The armature itself doesn't store all the bone shapes ('Custom Object' in 2.8+), it just *references* them (or the bones do). This means that when you append an armature that is using custom bone shapes it has to append the objects that are being used as the custom bone shapes *as well*. So what you are seeing is the armature *and* the custom shape objects it's referencing.

If you're in 2.79 you can just move the bone shape objects to a new layer or if you're in 2.8 you can move them to a new collection and hide them.

Comment: That's cleared it up Ray.